# AWS Cognitive Hosted UI display signed in username in asp.net core web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

We have implemented AWS Cognitive Hosted UI in my asp.net core web app and it works a treat. We would now like to display the user information of the signed in user but aren't sure how this can be implemented. Can someone point us to a working example?

Answer (score 0):

To access information regarding the signed in user you can use the following:

```
var username = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("cognito:username")).Value;
var givenname = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname")).Value;
var surname = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname")).Value;
```